Как оформить реферальную программу для бота телеграм библиотека aiogram
async def get_ref(message: types.Message):
  link = await create_start_link(str(message.from_user.username),encode=True)

  await message.answer(f"Ваша реф. ссылка {link}")




@dp.message(Command('start'))
async def handler(message: types.Message):
    args = message.get_args()
    reference = payload(args)
    await message.answer(f"Ваш реферал {reference}") 

Нужно сделать так, чтобы при прописывании определенной команды выдавалась реферальная ссылка, через которую можно будет приглашать друзей и получать очки за приглашение. Но я не понимаю как это оформить. Помогите!! Версия aiogram - 3.6.0

TypeError: create_start_link() missing 1 required positional argument: 'payload' выдает эту ошибку...
